# How do I assign just one Firebase Authenticate user id by one device despite of reinstalling the app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

It's just a simple question.

I just tried to install my app which does Firebase Authenticate anonymously to 
my android device.

*I just found that Firebase Authentication makes new user every time I remove the app from my device and reinstall the app.*

[image]

However, **I want one device to have just one authentication id and not to make Firebase Authentication make duplicate users.**

How can I do this? I thought I could do this by using Firebase Cloud Functions

and making it delete  every users that didn't log in for a long time.

But, I'm wondering if there is any simpler solution for this.

Comment: If authentication is done with gmail/google account, if found that the `User UID` of that gmail account remains same even if you reinstall the app and re-login with same gmail account multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Firebase Anonymous Authentication` accounts does not persist across application uninstalls. If you uninstall the app, everything that was saved locally on user devices will be deleted, including the `anonymous authentication token` that identifies their accounts. There is no way to reclaim a token for a particular user and use it in the future again. You can use Firebase Anonymous Authentication to create and use temporary accounts to authenticate users in your application.

If you want to have the same token each time, you need to implement the fully log in with a supported account provider so that they can log in from all their devices without worry of losing their data or having duplicate accounts.

Comment: Great answer Alex! Thanks for helping so many Firebase developers here on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Your products are awesome and I really love doing this. It's also educational and very satisfying. You're welcome and thank you too Frank!